# Drush error: "Command ... needs the following module(s) enabled to run: civicrm"

Tags: drupal, drush

I am trying to use Drush to run a CiviCRM command (for example, `civicrm-sql-dump` and although CiviCRM is enabled and running fine, I get the following type of error:

```
> drush civicrm-sql-dump > ~/dumpfile.sql

Command civicrm-sql-dump needs the following module(s) enabled to run: civicrm.
The drush command 'civicrm-sql-dump' could not be executed.
```

What is causing the problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For some reason the Drush cache is not up to date (for example, if you've recently upgraded CiviCRM). If you clear the Drush cache as follows, the command should work as expected:

```
> drush cc drush
```